# Foreign key from one column to another column contained in multiple column primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to create a foreign key between one column to two-column primary key and SQL Server refused that. Why ?

I have a table to store my wording in different languages and a country table.

```
    ref.SystemLabels
    --------------
--> [Id] int
|   [IdLanguage] int
|   Label nvarchar(200)
|   Keywords nvarchar(200)
|   
|   ref.Countries
|   --------------
|   [Id]
--> IdSystemLabel
    IsoCode
```

In my mind, it's very logic but I don't understand why SQL Server doesn't understand or accept my logic ^^.

If anyone can help me about this.

**NOTE** I think in another way, I will create an index on the IdSystemLabel despite of a foreign key.

---

EDIT: As you ask me, please see my SQL code for tables

**Table SystemLanguages**

```
CREATE TABLE [ref].[SystemLanguages](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdSystemLabel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsoCode] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SystemLanguages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [ref].[SystemLanguages] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SystemLanguages_Enabled]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Enabled]
GO
```

**Table SystemLabels**

```
CREATE TABLE [ref].[SystemLabels](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdLanguage] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Label] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Keywords] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
    [Group] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SystemLabels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [IdLanguage] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [ref].[SystemLabels] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SystemLabels_CreatedAt]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreatedAt]
GO
```

**NOTE** This table can't have foreign key to SystemLanguages due to circular dependency

**Table LocalizationLevel0**

```
CREATE TABLE [ref].[LocalizationLevel0](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdSystemLabel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsoCode] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LocalizationLevel0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [ref].[LocalizationLevel0] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_LocalizationLevel0_CreatedAt]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreatedAt]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ref].[LocalizationLevel0] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_LocalizationLevel0_Enabled]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Enabled]
GO
```

I'm trying to explain my logic :

One **localizationlevel0** item can have a translation in multiple system languages :

*Example for FRANCE country*

```
1 4 'FR' '2015-04-17 00:00:00:000' NULL 1
```

*-- System Languages*

```
1 1 'FR' 1
2 2 'EN' 1
3 3 'DE' 1
```

*-- Corresponding wordings*

```
1 1 'Français' NULL '2015-04-17 00:00:00:000' NULL 'SystemLanguages'
1 2 'French' NULL '2015-04-17 00:00:00:000' NULL 'SystemLanguages'
1 2 'Französisch' NULL '2015-04-17 00:00:00:000' NULL 'SystemLanguages'

...
4 1 'France' NULL '2015-04-17 00:00:00:000' NULL 'LocalizationLevel0'
4 2 'France' NULL '2015-04-17 00:00:00:000' NULL 'LocalizationLevel0'
4 3 'Frankreich' NULL '2015-04-17 00:00:00:000' NULL 'LocalizationLevel0'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Foreign keys and indexes are two different things...

Comment: What could it possibly mean to have a one column to two column foreign key? What kind of referential constraint would that impose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out the question IX in this article:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-primary-and-foreign-keys-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Comment: Ok so my second idea seems to be good. I must create a unique index on the Id column. Thanks for your answer ;-).

Answer (score 2):

You have to always reference *the whole* primary key.
So, if the first table has a composite primary key `(Id, IdLanguage)`, the second table has to have also a composite foreign key `(SystemLabels.Id, SystemLabels.Language)` and *not* just `(SystemLabels.Id)`.